# ASP.NET Core 2.2 GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity no longer exists

Tags: c#, .net-core, active-directory

I am trying to add a user to a group in AD, however the below example code no longer works:

```
UserPrincipal insUserPrincipal = (UserPrincipal)lbUsers.SelectedItem;
GroupPrincipal groupPrincipal = 
  GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(insPrincipalContext, group.GroupName);
if (groupPrincipal.Members.Contains(insPrincipalContext, 
    IdentityType.SamAccountName, insUserPrincipal.SamAccountName))
{
    MessageBox.Show(insUserPrincipal.Name + 
      " is already a member of group " + group.GroupName);
    return;
}
groupPrincipal.Members.Add(insUserPrincipal);
groupPrincipal.Save();
```

Does anyone know how to do this in asp.net core 2.2? I cant find a new version.

```
GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(insPrincipalContext, group.GroupName); //No longer exists
```

Edit: I can use GroupPrincipal to search for groups etc - however the method FindByIdentity is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement) on .NET Core, you will need to install the [NuGet package with the same name](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement) that provides this functionality. Once you have done that, you should be able to access the `GroupPrincipal` type again.

Comment: Hi, I have access to the GroupPrincipal Type - however there no longer seems to be a method called FindByIdentity?

Comment: @Hawke There is, are you sure you are looking at the right `GroupPrincipal` type? Did you include that package? What target framework are you using, .NET Core?

Comment: I am using package System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement and Core 2.2. Visual studio throws an error saying 'The type name 'FindByIdentity' does not exist in the type 'GroupPrincipal '.

Comment: Nevernind - it now works (cant even see the difference..)